# Regarding win10toast and win10toast-click, I have an issue with the Notification Center

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, notifications, toast

I have an issue regarding Python and Windows 10 toast notifications. What I would like to do is a windows toast that can be clickable AND that goes in the notification center if I don't click on it.

I know the existence of both `win10toast` and `win10toast-click`. The issue is that `win10toast` doesn't support `callback_on_click` and `win10toast-click` doesn't support the `Duration=None` parameter which allows the notification to go into the Notification Center if not clicked. I would like to find an easy way to do both but I unfortunately can't since I don't have the skills required to merge these two libraries.

Here is the code :

```py
from win10toast-click import ToastNotifier

def test():
  print('test')

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast(
    'Notification title',
    'Notification body',
    duration=None,
    icon_path='icon.ico',
    callback_on_click=test
) # Does not stand in the Notification Center
```

```py
from win10toast import ToastNotifier

def test():
  print('test')

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast(
    'Notification title', 
    'Notification body', 
    duration=None, 
    icon_path='icon.ico'
) # Stands in the Notification Center but does not support callback
```

Any of you have an idea ?
Thank you in advance...

Comment: first I would digg in source code to see how it works. Maybe it needs only to copy some part from one function to another. I expect that it could be simpler to copy `callback_on_click` because `duration` may need some timer which may have to run in `thread` and it may have more code.

Comment: you have code for [win10toast-click](https://github.com/vardecab/win10toast-click/blob/master/win10toast_click/__init__.py) and [win10toast](https://github.com/jithurjacob/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications/blob/master/win10toast/__init__.py) and for `duration` the only difference seems `if duration is not None:`. But for me it looks like `win10toast-click` should support `duration=None` and `win10toast` should raise error because it will try to run `sleep(None)`

Comment: @furas Yes, win10toast indeed raises this error but for the win10toast-click, yeah, no error is raised but it disappear instead of going in the Notification Center

Comment: maybe it is clue - when it raises error then it can't close it and it goes to Notification Center - so it is bug, not official method.

Comment: I think if you remove `if duration is not None:` from `win10toast-click` then it will raise error too and maybe it will work like in `win10toast`

Comment: The error is now being raised but still doesn't go in the Notification Center :/

Comment: @furas Do you have another idea ?

Comment: you will have to compare all code - maybe it uses something else.  I don't uses Windows so I can't even run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, for anyone having the same issue as me, I just found the perfect solution that does everything you intend to.

There is a recent library called [winotify](https://pypi.org/project/winotify/) which stands in the notification center, is **HIGHLY CUSTOMIZABLE** and can open links to your default browser.

Throw away `win10toast` and go for `winotify`!

Source code: [winotify's GitHub page](https://github.com/versa-syahptr/winotify)